# SQLite Recursive CTEs, query UP a hierachy

Tags: sqlite, recursion

In the example from the [docs](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html), a tree formed by rows that each have a parent id may be queried using `WITH RECURSIVE`.

```
CREATE TABLE org(
  name TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
  boss TEXT REFERENCES org
);
```

The example provided is a descendant query (i.e. do this for the node and all it's children):

```
WITH RECURSIVE
  works_for_alice(n) AS (
    VALUES('Alice')
    UNION
    SELECT name FROM org, works_for_alice
     WHERE org.boss=works_for_alice.n
  )
SELECT avg(height) FROM org
 WHERE org.name IN works_for_alice;
```

What would be the example for the opposite, specifically: The chain of command from Alice *up* until where Boss is null (i.e. the root node)? In contrast to the example, I simply need a list of the results, not do further processing.

Comment: `org.boss=works_for_alice.n` ->  `org.n=works_for_alice.boss`...

Comment: @LS_ᴅᴇᴠ In that case, I get a "no such column" error for `works_for_alice.boss`.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH RECURSIVE
  works_for_alice(n) AS (
    VALUES('Alice')
    UNION
    SELECT boss FROM org WHERE name=n AND boss IS NOT NULL
  )
SELECT avg(height) FROM org
 WHERE org.name IN works_for_alice;
```